# xampp 1.8.1 on Windows 8 issues with PHP code using Notepad++

Tags: windows-8, apache-http-server, php, mysql, notepad++

I am currently having a problem with xampp on windows 8. I installed xampp 1.8.1 and I didn't have any problems with the installation and I was able to configure Apache and MySQL just fine. But when I started to code using Notepad++ it wouldn't recognize any of the PHP code. I tried testing my work in a browser and it would only read the html code and skip over the PHP portion of my code. I've never had this problem with Windows 7. Any suggestions? I really have to get this working. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

How to use Xampp right under Win 8.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fxo4_DX4ejU

And dont forget to install the PHP Microsoft C++ Runtime Package.

And start setup_xampp.bat with Admin rights.

Comment: Hi, I've actually watched this video before I posted my question. This video did not help with the issue. I've even went as far as to removing skype from my laptop and I still have the same issue. But I do thank you for your help.